# Twitter callback not working with Cloud Run

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, twitter-oauth, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to create a website to make F1 predictions with flask
We started developing in Heroku, and the twitter API is already configured, you can check
https://demoflaskdance.herokuapp.com/
But now we are moving to Cloud Run as Heroku does not support pyodbc. We deployed our project, with the same code, and added to apps.twitter.com the urls, but when trying to log in with the link that google provided https://demo-flask-dance-kjomqyaifq-ew.a.run.app
we get an error and says that the URL is not authorized

Any help? Thanks

Comment: Your question lacks detail and is not a programming (but configuration) question. It will likely be closed as being off-topic on Stack Overflow. Presumably when you originally configured the Heroku app, your configured Twitter too so that, when the Heroku (and now Cloud Run) apps redirect to Twitter for authentication, Twitter knows where to redirect successful and unsuccessful responses. You do not include any details of the actual error you received in your question so it's difficult to guess but that is mine.

Answer (score 1):

If your Cloud Run application does not require **authenticated** access, enable public access.

- Go to the Google Cloud Console.
- Select the service you want to make public.
- Click Show Info Panel in the top right corner to show the Permissions tab.
- In the Add members field, allUsers
- Select the Cloud Run Invoker role from the Select a role drop-down menu.
- Click Add.

[Allowing public (unauthenticated) access](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/public)

If you require authenticated access see this document:

[Authentication overview](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/overview)